# Date of birth field change from drop-down to calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

We have a form build in **codeigniter** in which there is a field of Date of Birth (this field is a drop-down field as of now and We have an option to change the range (Start date and end date) of this field from our admin panel). In this way we don't need to change the .php file.

Date of Birth code in the .php file:

```
<div class="row-form">
    <div class="span3">Date Of Birth<font color="#FF0000">*</font></div>
       <div class="span9">
          <?php
            // Start date
             $date = $dob_start_date;
            // End date
            $end_date = $dob_end_date;
          ?>
         <select name="dob" id="dob" required>
          <?php
             while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
          ?>
          <option value="<?=$date?>" <?php if($dob==$date){ echo "selected";}?>><?=date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));?></option>
          <?php
            $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
            }
           ?>
          </select>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

We want to change this date of birth field from drop-down to calendar. Please help me guys how to change this field from drop-down to calendar.

We change the DOB range frequently. Its easy to change the DOB range from admin panel. But editing .php file is difficult. In our form there are 7 more fields like this, and all date fields range is adjustable from admin panel. We don't want to edit the .php files frequently.

Comment: use jquery datepicker

Comment: Why are you switching from the regular `<?php ?>` blocks to the short blocks `<? ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with DatePicker:

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/527zbs4s/

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-form">
  <div class="span3">Date Of Birth<font color="#FF0000">*</font></div>
  <div class="span9">
    <input name="dob" id="dob" required type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dob").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    defaultDate: '-18y'
  });
});
```

An easy way is to set the value, using `value="<?php echo $dob_start_date; ?>"`. You can also pass `defaultDate` a Date Object from JS (that could be fed with a date string from PHP), a Number of days from today (2, or -1), or a String like '-18y' or '+1m'... There are lots more ways to improve this: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Thanks for relying. We change the DOB range frequently. Its easy to change the range from admin panel. But editing .php file is difficult. In our form there are 7 more fields like this, and all date fields range is adjustable from admin panel. We don't want to edit the .php files frequently.

Comment: You referred to this in the original post and it was not clear then, nor is it clear now how this is relevant to your goal. What is it you're trying to accomplish?